# How to detect mouse click in GtkComboBox?

Tags: gtk, mouse, mouseevent

ALL,
In GTK+ there is a widget called GtkComboBox. I don't know the implementation details but on Windows it consists of 2 widgets: text control and list control. There is also a little button to the right of the text control. If you click that button, the list control pops up.

My question is: how do I detect the mouse click on that button in GtkComboBox? Is such click even emits the signal that can be caught or it just sends the popdown signal to the GtkComboBox widget and eats the mouse click?

BTW is it a composite widget in GTK+ as well?

An example on any language would be much helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: "on Windows" is a complete red herring where GTK+ is concerned because it does not apply any platform-specific behaviour/widgets. What you see is what you get on any platform. (This is often derided as a drawback, but as a programmer, I vastly prefer it.) Also, `ComboBox` only has a text control if set appropriately; none of mine do, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The GtkComboBox does in fact "eat the mouse click" and I think it will be quite tricky to get the behavior you are looking for without modifying or subclassing the GtkComboBox widget.  I wouldn't rely on the GtkComboBox being a composite widget or not - that seems like an implementation detail that could change.

It seems like you're paddling upstream if you really want to capture mouse clicks on the combo box - after all, there are other ways for users to use the widget (with the keyboard, for example).  The GtkComboBox emits a `changed` signal whenever the selection changes - could you use that in your application?

Comment: Yes, I tried to send an E-mail, but nobody responded. :( Anyway I'm not trying to rely on it being composite it's just BTW. The thing is I'm not trying to catch mouse click on the text area - only on the drop-down button. So from what I understand it's just how GTK+ works. You can catch mouse click on the text control and you can't on the drop-down arrow as in this case it will send "popdown/popup" signals.